# Encrypted html will cache or not?

Tags: javascript, caching

To protect my css file i encrypted the css link using java script .This works cool,but i had one doubt that my css file will cache when i use the normal specified url with name.css, now the encrypted css link will cache or not?

```
<Script Language='Javascript'>
document.write(unescape('3%73%22%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A2%2F%3E%09%0A'));
</Script>
```

Comment: LOL? And you really believe this "protects" the CSS file? From what, to begin with?

Comment: This may not protect 100% .From my point of view by hiding .css link ,some people may stop thinking about copying my webpage.

Comment: I will leave whatever you do with your site up to you, but seriously: if someone wants to copy your site, this will not really detract them. More likely nobody is interested in copying your site and you're really just wasting your own time worrying about it.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it deterred 1% of people who were interested in seeing your CSS. Browsers do have DOM inspectors these days.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your valuable suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this will simply result in a CSS element being inserted into the document (or so I guess), which then causes the browser to download the external file as usual, all the usual caching rules apply.